# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples when fitting LogisticRegression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am creating [`LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) classifier with the following code:

```
regressor = LogisticRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Both `x_train` and `y_train` shapes are

```
<class 'tuple'>: (32383,)
```

`x_train` contains values around range `[0..1]`, and `y_train` contains only `0`s and `1`s.

Unfortunately, `fit` fails with error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 32383]
```

Adding transpose to arguments doesn't help.

Comment: Try to reshape the x_train so that it will be (32383,1). The error that you get it is related to the shape of the x_train

Comment: I just posted an example following my previous comment. I used tuples as you have. Let me know if you solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue the solution that I proposed in my comment:
The problem is the shape of the x_train. So we need to reshape it:

From the documentation:

X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)

y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)

**Example** using **scikit-learn** and **numpy**:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np

# create the tuple data
x_train = tuple(range(32383))
x_train = np.asarray(x_train)

#same for y_train
y_train=tuple(range(32383))
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)

#convert tuples to nparray and reshape the x_train
x_train = x_train.reshape(32383,1)

#check if shape if (32383,)
y_train.shape

#create the model
lg = LogisticRegression()

#Fit the model
lg.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This should work fine.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I guess a little reshaping is necessary. I tried it like this :

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    import numpy as np 


    #x_train = np.random.randn(10,1)
    x_train = np.asarray(x_train).reshape(32383,1)
    con = np.ones_like(x_train)


    x_train = np.concatenate((con,x_train), axis =1)


    #y = np.random.randn(10,1)
    #y_train = np.where(y<0.5,1,0)
    y_train = np.asarray(y_train).reshape(32383,1)
    regressor = LogisticRegression()
    regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

The comments are just what i did to create some data. And dont forget to ad a constant like in the example, as far as i know sklearn isn't doing it. Also Statsmodels could be helpfull to you if you are interested in some statistical test and a pretty print of the results :

```
    from statsmodels.api import Logit

    logit =Logit(y_train, x_train)

    fit= logit.fit()
    fit.summary()
```

That will give you a little more statistical intel without much effort.